# Visibility of ContentNote records

Tags: soql, developer-console

This could be a general Developer Console issue as well, but as of now it pertains to the `ContentNote` object.

I am trying to run a query in an apex class that will looks at related `Content Notes` on `Opportunities`.  The problem I am running into, is that myself and other users cannot see the `ContentNotes`.  In the developer console query I can only see `ContentNotes` created by myself (`Select id From ContentNote`).  However if I explicitly put a `WHERE` clause with an `Id`, I can see that record in the dev console (`Select id From ContentNote WHERE id = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'`).

When I queried for the `SharingPrivacy` of the `ContentNote` I get `"N"` for all of them - the ones I can only see when I specify an ID. I also have a trigger that is setting the `Visibility` field of `ContentDocumentLink to 'AllUsers`' so that record shouldn't be the problem.

Is there anything else that could be blocking me from querying the ContentNote records?

- I can also see all AttachedContentNotes `(SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id FROM AttachedContentNotes)`
  FROM Opportunity) without having to specify an ID, but that isn't the solution to my problem
- The parent object - `Opportunity` has sharing settings set to `Private`, however as the system admin, I can query all opportunities.
- The `ContentNotes` have the message `'Visibility Set by Record'`

Comment: Are you able to navigate to the detail pages for ContentNote records that you don't own?

Comment: @Brand0R, yes I can type the Id into the URL and view the record detail page

Answer (score 2):

If the `ConentNotes` records you're attempting to query reside under [Libraries](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=content_workspace_create.htm&type=5) that are marked as 'Private' this could be the issue. Private libraries cannot be accessed by System Admins. They can only be Accessed by library owners.

This came from the developer forums where someone asked a similar question [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000kA6aIAE).

Additionally, you can check the sharing settings that exist on parent records and ensure they aren't set to private.

Comment: They are not in Libraries, but you did make me check the sharing settings on the parent record which are set to private. Updating my original post

Comment: I updated my solution to include that as a suggestion.

Comment: So I'm guessing that would be the problem.  Is there a workaround or will I simply have to query individual Ids to see the notes?